# Docker - initdb .sql not running in postgresql composed container

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I've been scratching my head with this issue for a while now. I can't seem to get docker-compose to run the .sql that I specified.
My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
# a fastapi service
  ms_appointments:
    build: .
    container_name: "ms_appointments"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://appointments_ms:gingerberries203@ms_db_appointments:5432/appointments_db
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - ms_db_appointments
    networks:
      - clowning-around-local-network

  ms_db_appointments:
# the service in question
    image: postgres:11.3-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=appointments_ms
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=gingerberries203
      - POSTGRES_DB=appointments_db
    # attempted copying the .sql through a Dockerfile; but that didn't work either
    # build:
    #   context: ./db
    container_name: "ms_db_appointments"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./db/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    networks:
      - clowning-around-local-network

volumes:
  local_postgres_data:

networks:
  clowning-around-local-network:
    external: true
```

And this is schema.sql:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS appointments_db;

CREATE DATABASE appointments_db;

\c appointments_db;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Appointments (
    appointment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    date_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    date_of_appointment TIMESTAMP,
    client_id INTEGER,
    troupe_id INTEGER,
    status TEXT,
    rating TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Appointments(date_created, date_of_appointment, client_id, troupe_id, status, rating)
VALUES
    ('2021-01-20 14:31:11', '2021-01-30 18:00:00', 4, 1, 'upcoming', NULL),
    ('2021-01-20 08:54:06', '2021-02-18 18:00:00', 11, 2, 'upcoming', NULL),
    ('2021-01-20 14:31:11', '2021-01-01 17:00:00', 11, 1, 'completed', '\ud83e\udd21'),
    ('2021-01-21 10:30:34', '2020-01-22 18:00:00', 11, 4, 'cancelled', NULL),
    ('2021-01-21 14:13:49', '2020-01-23 18:00:00', 11, 4, 'upcoming', NULL),
    ('2021-01-21 14:14:14', '2020-01-23 19:00:00', 11, 4, 'upcoming', NULL),
    ('2021-01-26 08:20:04', '2020-01-22 19:00:21', 11, 4, 'upcoming', NULL),
    ('2021-01-26 08:20:26', '2020-01-22 20:00:00', 11, 4, 'upcoming', NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Appointment_Issues (
    appointment_issues_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    appointment_id INTEGER REFERENCES Appointments(appointment_id),
    clown_id INTEGER,
    title TEXT,
    description TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Appointment_Issues(appointment_id, clown_id, title, description)
VALUES
    (4, 13, 'Address is too far', 'It would take me 3 hours to drive from my home to the clients specified address.'),
    (4, 13, 'Client stinks', 'Seriously. This guys smell is ruining my pazzas.');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clowns_View_Client_Details (
    clowns_view_client_details_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    appointment_id INTEGER REFERENCES Appointments(appointment_id),
    clown_id INTEGER,
    reason TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Clowns_View_Client_Details(appointment_id, clown_id, reason)
VALUES
    (4, 13, 'Need to ask the client for the address.'),
    (4, 13, 'Request that the client takes a bath.');
```

And finally, the local filesystem:

```
app
|  api
|  main.py
db
|  schema.sql
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile
```

After inspecting the container's filesystem using `docker exec -t -i <container_id> /bin/bash`, it seems that the .sql did copy into the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. But as stated, it doesn't seem to run whenever I run the compose file.
Any advice would be appreciated...